# drag and drop metro control to windows form does not work in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, nuget-package

I just imported the nuget package into visual studio 2013. I found that all the metro control in toolbox cannot be added on the windows form, and they will display on the panel under the windows form. How can i solve this?

Comment: what package is that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43160829/3703534

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are adding third party user controls into your solution through nuget.

The first thing I will check is to see if the dll files (your third party library) have been added to the project properly.

The second thing is do a rebuild on the whole solution.