# Metro UI controls not showing on form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have installed metro ui from nuGet package installer. Tools added in toolbox and also added reference. But when I drag a control and drop on form it does not show on form instead form components. someone please help

Comment: Did you add MetroFramework.dll , MetroFramework.Design.dll files to your project references ?

Comment: yes I added it to my project

Comment: I am going to try it. and sure I will tell you and vote up after trying it

Comment: Thank for your response

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Manage `Nuget` Packages dialog, there are few versions of the Metroframework. download the one by *Dennis Magno* only. it will have a updated version 1.4.0.0 19/07/16.it works best.

[image]

Or else

you can install `MetroModernUI` by ,open Package Manager Console
**Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console** then type `Install-Package MetroModernUI` in there. now open your project folder and check this path `\packages\MetroModernUI.1.4.0.0\lib\net\` .In there have 3 `.dll` files

- MetroFramework.Design.dll
- MetroFramework.dll
- MetroFramework.Fonts.dll

add these 3 files to your project reference,hope this will be helped to you :)

Comment: it's my pleasure :)